# BLTouch on Bed Leveling check don't move left after point 6

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch

**My Setup**

- Ender 3
- BTT SKR Mini E3 v1.2 with BLTouch
- Marlin v2.1.x

**Problem**

Captured it here (short video):

When Bed Leveling, the print head doesn't return left on the X-Axis although in the LCD display it does mark that the X value is modified.

This is a sudden behavior. I've tried to upgrade my firmware from Marlin 2.0 to Marlin 2.1 and the problem still persists.

Auto Home is working properly and I'm able to move the printhead in all directions through the graphical interface after homing.

**Disclaimer**

I'm very new to 3D printing.

Comment: If a printer doesn't move towards the endstops, it could be that there is a problem with the endstop cable, please check the cable and the values of the endstops by hooking up a [console](/q/10573) and run G-code `M119`. Please investigate and add this to your question by [edit].